# Now when there is no neon/kf5 ppa, how can I install KDE 5 in gnome Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, kde, ppa, plasma

All the other posts suggest to use the neon/kf5 but that doesn't work since early December. How can I do it now?

Comment: Neon has been replaced by the Kubuntu ci: https://blogs.kde.org/2014/11/20/kubuntu-ci-replacement-project-neon . Supported Kubuntu versions are limited to: 14.10 and 15.04 : https://community.kde.org/Kubuntu/PPAs#Kubuntu_Continuous_Integration_.28CI.29

Comment: So, does that mean I cannot install KDE 5 on my Ubuntu 14.04? I do not want to stray away from the LTS.

Comment: You can upgrade to the following LTS.