# How to update kde version to kde plasma 5 on Kubuntu 14.04.3?

Tags: kubuntu, plasma-5, kde5

I have installed **kubuntu 14.04.3** in my laptop, when I check the version of kde its shows as follows,

[image]

When I tried `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:neon/kf5` in terminal, am getting response as,

```
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:neon/kf5'.
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.
```

I wish to update kde into Plasma 5. How to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Neon has been replaced by Kubuntu CI (https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ci/+archive/ubuntu/stable). In any case this is a release for KDE developers. There is also a new KDE Neon project which can serve to install up-to-date KDE, but is currently also only available as unstable release (and not intended for Kubuntu 14.04).
http://neon.kde.org.uk/download

The solution is to update your Kubuntu to version 15.10
http://www.kubuntu.org/news/kubuntu-15-10/
which will give you a Plasma 5 version already.

Then you may add kubuntu-backports ppa to get recent bugfixes. The above mentioned KDE Neon project can then also be installed through a ppa, but be aware that this controversial project just started and stable releases are not yet available.

Possibly related question: [Now when there is no neon/kf5 ppa, how can I install KDE 5 in gnome Ubuntu 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/584232/now-when-there-is-no-neon-kf5-ppa-how-can-i-install-kde-5-in-gnome-ubuntu-14-04)